# Right place to add general code in Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am developing a Lightswitch 2012 greenfield application.  I am very new to Lightswitch, so my approach may be completely wrong.

I have a UserProfile table that provides additional user details and that I am planning to use to query for user data as needed.  I want to add a general use method that looks up the appropriate record for the current user.  The following code is in-line where one of my screens needs to consume this information:

```
        UserProfile myProfile;
        {
            var profiles = this.DataWorkspace.ApplicationData.UserProfiles;
            string myDomainId = Application.User.Name;
            myProfile = (from profile in profiles.OfType<UserProfile>()
                         where profile != null && profile.DomainId == myDomainId
                         select profile).FirstOrDefault<UserProfile>();
            if (myProfile == null)
            {
                myProfile = profiles.AddNew();
                myProfile.DomainId = myDomainId;
            }
        }
```

Right now this code runs in one of the onsave routines in one of my screens.  I'd like to refactor this for general use into a GetCurrentUserProfile() method.  I first tried putting this in the application, but I got context errors.

Where is the right place to put that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've started to find myself explaining the same thing over & over, as more new people start wanting to use LightSwitch in a more advanced way. This is a great thing to see, so to make it a little easier, I'll be adding little "How To's" to my **LightSwitch Central** site.

Here's the first one: [How Do I Refactor Code That I'm Using In One Of My Screens, So I Can Use It In Other Screens?](http://lightswitchcentral.net.au/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/28/How-Do-I-Refactor-Code-That-Im-Using-In-One-Of-My-Screens-So-I-Can-Use-It-In-Other-Screens.aspx)
I hope it helps.

Comment: The link is dead. Maybe this is an appropriate update [MSDN Forum: Where to place custom code that is global to all lightswitch entites?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dd9e3328-66ab-4702-80a3-b0bacee56e70/where-to-place-custom-code-that-is-global-to-all-lightswitch-entites?forum=lightswitch)

Comment: Thanks spikey. I've switched away from using DNN for my blog. I'm gradually moving posts to www.yannduran.com/blog, but that particular post isn't there yet. The link that you provided isn't appropriate for current LightSwitch development, as there's no Common project anymore, & all client-side code is JavaScript (though you still use C#/VB for server-side code).

Answer (score 0):

Remember that if you want to do something whith data, you must to pass to the new method the current dataworkspace.